# Select category between two date in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have this Table in mysql. I want to select data as "rc_type" between "start_date" & "end_date".

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+                     
| id | rc_type| start_date | end_date   |                
+----+--------+------------+------------+  
|  1 |  Gold  | 16-05-2016 | 22-05-2016 |                          
|  2 | Silver | 20-05-2016 | 29-05-2016 |             
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

My html form has these three fields. So how to find `rc_type`?

[image]

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type='silver' BETWEEN '16-05-2016' AND '17-05-2016'
```

And also:

```
SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= '16-05-2016' AND end_date <= '17-05-2016' AND rc_type='Gold'
```

If I select start date as 16-05-2016 and end date as 17-05-2016 with "silver" category selection, I got result with "Gold" category. Actually there is no silver type between this two dates.

I don't get proper data. Kindly Help to get proper Data.

Comment: What is your filed type in MySQL ?

Comment: For avoiding data format problem i use "varchar" .

Comment: actually because your data column is varchar you have problem with date format

Comment: @mitkosoft sir, actually i  get the result if i  check for '16-05-2016' AND '17-05-2016'' with "rc_type='gold' . if there is any date format problem it show an error. but i didn't get any error.

Comment: You have chosen an evil data type `varchar` for storing the dates and this should be fixed first and use mysql's native data related data types.

Comment: In which database field of your `End Date` html input you want to search? Ie. Start Date > start_date, End Date > end_date or?

Comment: i want to do like this : if i enter start_date = '16-05-2016' & end_date = '17-05-2016' and "Silver"  then probably i don't get a data. but in reality i get the data which have  same date but "gold" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate presentation from real data type, i.e. is better to convert your date columns to real date format instead of varchar. However in order to get proper result you need to convert there strings to proper dates:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    room_inventory
WHERE
    rc_type = 'Silver'
    AND STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('15-05-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('30-05-2016', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | rc_type | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
|  2 | Silver  | 20-05-2016 | 29-05-2016 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

If you don't do such converts, you will get incorrect results as follow (I have changed Silver's end date to 29-06-2016):

Input:

```
mysql> select * from room_inventory;
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | rc_type | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Gold    | 16-05-2016 | 22-05-2016 |
|  2 | Silver  | 20-05-2016 | 29-06-2016 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    room_inventory
WHERE
    rc_type = 'Silver'
    AND start_date > '15-05-2016'
    AND end_date < '30-05-2016';
```

Output (wrong):

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | rc_type | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
|  2 | Silver  | 20-05-2016 | 29-06-2016 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

This is because MySQL performs char-by-char comparison and decides that `29-06-2016 < 30-05-2016` which is wrong. So in general you will have further problems if you keep dates columns in varchar format.

Comment: i tried this " 'SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type = 'silver' AND STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('16-05-2016', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('17-05-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')'" but steel didn't get the proper result.

Comment: yes because you don't have end_date < 2016-05-17, all dates there are biggher than 17.05.

Comment: i didn't change my database i have same database as in the question

Comment: exactly. all end_date values in YOUR DATABASE are bigger than 17.05. you are trying to get result with end_date < 17.05 - such rows doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: No sir, i tried your given sql query but it doesn't came up with any result

Comment: you wrote above that you have tried with `STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('17-05-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')` which is different from my query.

Comment: Ok i change varcare to Data Datatype

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong date format,
correct is **year-month-day**

also you had missing the date column in your query, in this example the query search silver category where start date between 2016-06-16 and 2016-05-17

```
SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type='silver' BETWEEN '2016-05-16' AND '2016-05-17'
```

Comment: sorry sir but i need day-month-year format. and this  try your sql query but it came up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of 'between'  try this:

```
SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type='silver' AND start_date = '16-05-2016' AND end_date = '17-05-2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Danilo mentioned you are using wrong date format,

Another thing is your query formate of comparing date syntax is wrong.

correct syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type='silver' AND Your Date BETWEEN '2016-05-16' AND '2016-05-17'.
```

But here you are comparing two dates so this query won't work as your expectation.

With second query please correct your date format as:

```
'SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= '2016-05-16' AND end_date <= '2016-05-17' AND rc_type = 'Gold''
```

Comment: i tried your query dear, but i didn't get any data in return.

Comment: What is your data type for both dates: start and end date? Nad another thing if you are getting result with "Gold", There is a small spelling mistake in "Silver". Your data column contains capital S. try this also.

Answer (score 0):

Logical error , You are use **between** for two columns in a table. **between** is used to compare in **between** one columns ,so you can use **AND** instead of  between .

`SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE rc_type='silver' AND start_date = '16-05-2016' AND end_date = '17-05-2016'`